# How to crawl several elements at once?

Tags: python, scrapy

There is a web site with several elements on the page. The problem is that I don't know how to crawl them correctly using Scrapy.

This is my piece of code:

```
class IdSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'id'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['example.com/page/1']
    deep_level = 1
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'.*'), callback='parse_item1', follow=True),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'.*'), callback='parse_item2', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item1(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        i = IdeeItem()
        i['website']    =   sel.xpath("""/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[4]/td/h4/text()""").extract()
        i['title']  =   sel.xpath("""/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[2]/td/h4/text()""").extract()
        return i


    def parse_item2(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        i = IdeeItem()
        i['website']    =   sel.xpath("""/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[6]/td/h4/text()""").extract()
        i['email']  =    sel.xpath("""//html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[8]/td/a[1]/text()""").extract()
        return i
```

I expected that web-page will be parsed by parse_item1 and parse_item2. But only parse_item1 is working. How to make them running simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first matching rule will be followed by `CrawlSpider`:

> If multiple rules match the same link, the first one will be used, according to the order they’re defined in this attribute.

([from the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules))

You have a couple options:

**Defining a generator callback using `yield`**

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'.*'), callback='parse_items', follow=True),
)

def parse_items(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)

    i = IdeeItem()
    i['website']    =   sel.xpath("""/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[4]/td/h4/text()""").extract()
    i['title']  =   sel.xpath("""/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[2]/td/h4/text()""").extract()
    yield i

    i = IdeeItem()
    i['website']    =   sel.xpath("""/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[6]/td/h4/text()""").extract()
    i['email']  =    sel.xpath("""//html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[8]/td/a[1]/text()""").extract()
    yield i
```

Or calling the 2 callbacks 1 after the other:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'.*'), callback='parse_items', follow=True),
)

def parse_items(self, response, sel=None):
    sel = Selector(response)
    for r in self.parse_item1(response, sel):
        yield r

    for r in self.parse_item2(response, sel):
        yield r

def parse_item1(self, response, sel=None):
    if sel is None:
        sel = Selector(response)
    i = IdeeItem()
    i['website']    =   sel.xpath("""/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[4]/td/h4/text()""").extract()
    i['title']  =   sel.xpath("""/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[2]/td/h4/text()""").extract()
    return i

def parse_item2(self, response, sel=None):
    if sel is None:
        sel = Selector(response)
    i = IdeeItem()
    i['website']    =   sel.xpath("""/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[6]/td/h4/text()""").extract()
    i['email']  =    sel.xpath("""//html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[4]/div/table/tr[8]/td/a[1]/text()""").extract()
    return i
```